# Average age of the class

Tags: linear-algebra

The average age of girls in a class of 42 students is 13 years. The average age of all the boys as well as the average age of 23 of the boys of the same class is 16 years. Which of the following could be the average age of the total students in the class? (in years)
a. 13.5
b. 14
c. 14.5
d. 15

I am looking for the trick of how to solve the above question.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Which of the following what, for the average age of all of the students? Also, when you add this to your question text, please also provide what you've tried so, including anything you had difficulty with, as well as possibly other context such as where the question comes from. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, i missed to update the options.. i have updated the same in the question..

Comment: Hint: What is the minimum # of boys (and, thus, maximum # of girls) and how does this affect the overall average compared to their individual averages?

Comment: I have tried this way by taking minimum of 23 boys and thus max of 19 girls. But this way i am getting the average of 14.6, which is wrong. Correct answer is 15. I need the way to solve this?

Comment: I suggest you add your comment above to the end of your question text, since not everyone reads the comments, as it shows that you have made some effort with answering your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $b$ be the number of boys and $g$ be the number of girls, so $b + g = 42$, i.e., $g = 42 - b$ and the average age of all of them is

$$A = \frac{16b + 13(42 - b)}{42} = \frac{3b + 546}{42} \tag{1}\label{eq1}$$

As you've stated in a comment, the minimum # of boys is $23$ and the maximum # of girls is $19$, with \eqref{eq1} showing this gives an average value of

$$\frac{3 \times 23 + 546}{42} \approx 14.6 \tag{2}\label{eq2}$$

However, the number of boys could be larger, with the # of girls then being correspondingly smaller, so the average age would increase since the boy's average age is greater than that of girls. This is shown on the RHS of \eqref{eq1} as this value increases as $b$ increases. Thus, among the $4$ choices, only the last one, i.e., (d) of 15, could be the correct one.

As for determining what the # of boys would be to get, at least approximately, this answer, from \eqref{eq1} we have

$$15 = \frac{3b + 546}{42} \implies 630 = 3b + 546 \implies b = 28 \tag{3}\label{eq3}$$

Thus, the number of boys would be $28$ and the number of girls would be $42 - 28 = 14$.

Comment: Thanks John. That makes sense. With your hint provided above, i was also in the same direction.

Comment: But can we solve this if we dont have any options provided?

Comment: @user706777:  without the options you could give a range the average could be in.  You need at least $1$ girl for there to be an average and at most $19$.  Compute the average in both cases and say it is somewhere in there.

Comment: @user706777 I have expanded my answer to show you the actual # of boys which correspond to the only option in the answer which works. As for solving "this" without any options provided, I'm not quite sure what you mean. From the original question text, without any particular restrictions such as the options provided, then the number of boys can be anything from $23$ to $41$, with the corresponding # of girls being $19$ to $1$. As Ross' comment indicates, one possibility would be to be given a range which the overall average must fit within.